# HIVE: GROUP BY doesn't behave as it would in MySQL

Tags: database, group-by, hive

I have some experience with MySQL and recently I have to do some work on HIVE instead.

The basic structure of the queries is quite similar between the two, but the GROUP BY in HIVE seems to work a bit differently... Thus I cannot achieve what I could previously achieve in MySQL using GROUP BY.

Following is my question, so say I have a table with column A, B, C, and I want to select the rows with max. B column values grouping by column A. I will do:

```
SELECT A, max(B) FROM myTable GROUP BY A
```

The above code would work in HIVE with no problem. But what if I also want to see the value in column C which is in the same row of the row with max. B value? In MySQL I can just do:

```
SELECT A, max(B), C FROM myTable GROUP BY A
```

But in HIVE I can't do this. It complains that C is not in the GROUP BY keys, but if I add C into GROUP BY, the result is totally not what I want.

So what is the way to select such desired result in HIVE? Some say using collect_set on column C can solve the problem, but I have no idea how the collect_set is ordered and thus don't know which element to return...

Comment: Hive rejects that... but so do all other databases in the world besides MySQL. It's not a well-defined query. (for example: what if max(B) occurs in multiple rows? Which value for C should get returned?)

Comment: @mdahlman yes I think maybe you are right...

Comment: @mdahlman : if I'm sure that this `(max(B) occurs in multiple rows)` will not happen in my use case, will there be a workaround for this?

Comment: MySQL doesn't return "the value in column C which is in the same row of the row with max B value" like you suggest -- the server can return ANY value of C, from ANY row.  The only consistent use of the syntax you're suggesting is if C takes on unique values for every unique value of A -- otherwise you'll get undefined results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay I figured this out... The following would do the trick:

```
SELECT A, maxB, C FROM myTable JOIN
(SELECT A, max(B) as maxB FROM myTable GROUP BY A) temp
ON myTable.A = temp.A AND myTable.B = temp.maxB
```

It turns out that I have to write much more code in HIVE to get the same result as I would get with just one line in MySQL... :(

Comment: @SagarNikam then would you please suggest a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you would just get a random C, which is not the one you seem to expect.

See MySQL's SQL_MODE to appropriately let MySQL also refuse such ambiguous code.

(or use MIN(C), to get a specific one)