# Printing the highest value in a table using group by

Tags: hive, hiveql

First of all, sorry for the confusing title, I don't know how to describe it any better, it's complicated.

I have a table that looks like this:

| send_org | rec_org | partecipants |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | b | 1 |
| a | c | 2 |
| b | d | 2 |
| b | c | 3 |
| b | f | 3 |

and so on.

What I'm trying to print, for each *send*, is the row with the highest *partecipants* number (I don't care about duplicates, I need just one row with the highest number); so, in this case, I'm expecting something like

```
a c 2
b c 3
```

With MySQL, my query would be

```sql
SELECT send_org, receive_org, partecipants  
FROM (  
  SELECT *   
  FROM tab
  ORDER BY partecipants DESC) p  
GROUP BY send_org;
```

and it works.

Hive gives me errors about the keys not in the GROUP BY statement, so I tried to switch to collection_set(), with something like this

```sql
SELECT send_org, collect_set(receive_org)[0], max(partecipants) partecipants  
FROM tab  
GROUP BY send_org  
ORDER BY partecipants;
```

But the collection_set()[0] returns the first value in the column *rec* (correctly grouped), not the value related to the partecipants number.
Do you have any suggestion?

If you need a better view of the SQL version, it is [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d1c45/1).

Comment: tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741891/hive-group-by-doesnt-behave-as-it-would-in-mysql?rq=1) , doesn't work. Now i got this error `FAILED: SemanticException Column send_org Found in more than One Tables/Subqueries`

Comment: If you are writing this in SPARK sql not hive you could us:

Comment: SELECT send_org, first(rec_org), MAX(partecipants) from tab group by send_org;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `row_number` to determine the *"row with the highest partecipants number"* eg.

```sql
SELECT send_org, receive_org, partecipants  
FROM (  
  SELECT 
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY send_org
          ORDER BY partecipants DESC
      ) rn
  FROM tab
) p  
where rn=1
```